# ant fixcrlf include/exclude does not work

Tags: java, filter, ant, file-conversion

I am having little problem with **fixcrlf** from ant. When I try to compile for unix target with fixcrlf filter, it modifies all files in the target folder, no matter of includes and excludes. I expect it should not convert any files that are not in the includes patterns, or at least I could force some files to not be converted via excludes attribute. None of that I tried been able to exclude anything. Even some binary files are modified and as result screwed up.
According to [fixcrlf documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fixcrlf.html) from apache site, these parameters should work like this:
**includes**: comma- or space-separated list of patterns of files that must be included.
**excludes**: comma- or space-separated list of patterns of files that must be excluded.
When I run ant with parameters -verbose and -debug, there is no information on that fixcrlf did.

```
    <copy todir="target">
        <fileset dir="source1"><exclude name="**/*.bak"/></fileset>
        <fileset dir="source2"><exclude name="**/*.bak"/></fileset>
        <filterchain>
            <fixcrlf srcdir="${src}" includes="**/*.sh,**/*.properties" excludes="**/*.xml" eol="lf" />
        </filterchain>
    </copy>
```